# how to copy multiple text files in to excel sheets by python

Tags: python, excel, copy, text-files

I have 20 text files. i have to open them in excel's sheets (in 1 excel file with different sheets with same name of that text file). can anyone please suggest me the logic and which package is good for that. i am new in python so

Comment: If you just want a package try looking into `Pandas`and its DataFrames

Comment: thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/). You should figure out logic yourself, get back when you have more specific questions.